# in node.js express, request to '/locations/search' always goes to '/locations/:location_id', how to route in the right way

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node.js express to build a simple web api, such like this

```
app.get('/locations/:location_id',getLocationByID);   -- first form
app.get('/locations/search',searchLocation);    -- second form
```

However, when the url is structured in the second form, '/locations/search', the request would always goes to the first kind. How can I intelligently tell the express to separate from these two different form of url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do /search first.

```
app.get('/locations/search',searchLocation);
app.get('/locations/:location_id',getLocationByID);
```

Express processes routes in the order they're added.

Comment: this is a good quick solution, no need to use Regular Expression